# Count results in left join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

trying to make the move to MySQLi and some of it is baffling me. Quick question as my query is currently saying there's 1 result even if there isn't one...

How do I go about finding the number of rows returned for this:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT u.*, t.*
    FROM Users u
    LEFT JOIN Transactions t USING (UserID) 
    WHERE UserID = $UserID
    ORDER BY Date DESC
    LIMIT 5
SQL;
```

Presently it is returning 1 result from an empty table with all the values being null.

Comment: Its because of left join, left join will return NULL for the joining table in your case Transactions.

Comment: This doesn't result in an ambiguity error

Comment: Oh, how do I go about filtering and showing the results then? Because at the moment it is showing a row that is completely wrong and I'm confused as to how I differentiate between no results and results.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to place the value instead of $UserID. Then, you should try to run this query in MySQL.

Also, check your code which processes query results.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting results when there weren't any was because of using Left Join which nulls any results that don't match. as was pointed out in comments. I needed Inner Join instead, which is working as required.